# Is there any good way to DRY up scope / predicate logic duplication?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, scope, dry

For example, consider the following code (in a model):

```
scope :popular, where("views >= 250 OR (views >= 10 AND avg_rating >= 4.75)")

def popular?
  views >= 250 or views >= 10 && avg_rating >= 4.75
end
```

First condition is SQL, second one is ruby, but still, there's an obvious duplication. Is there any good way to DRY it up? What is best practice for such cases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are good reasons to have both so I might consider this (all in model):

```
VIEWS_QUALIFIER = 250
RATING_VIEWS_QUALIFIER = 10
RATING_QUALIFIER = 4.75

scope :popular, where("views >= ? OR (views >= ? AND avg_rating >= ? ",
                VIEWS_QUALIFIER, RATING_VIEWS_QUALIFIER, RATING_QUALIFIER)

def popular?
  views >= VIEWS_QUALIFIER or 
  (views >= RATING_VIEWS_QUALIFIER && avg_rating >= RATING_QUALIFIER)
end
```

Answer (score -1):

```
def popular?
  !!self.class.popular.includes? self
end
```

Comment: Would advise against above as this would load up all popular records just to check the one item is popular. Maybe `self.class.popular.exists?(id)` might work

Comment: @ThongKuah there's also another problem with all similar solutions - the method may possibly return wrong result when object is in a 'dirty' and `views` or `avg_rating` is changed but not saved

Comment: There is always a place for learning in SO. TY for the comments! :)

Comment: @Alexis yeah I realised that soon after :)